# Righting a stone column that is tilting

Tags: structural

I have concrete driveway piers with a stone facade and one of them is tilting like the leaning tower of Pisa. How can I right it and keep it stable?

Comment: Please describe your piers in more detail. Height, depth, thickness, footing situation, soil composition.

Comment: Most likely the ground is heaving and moving that one because the support is too shallow, needs to do down deeper than the frost line to be stable.

Comment: Give it a proper foundation...

Answer (score 1):

How handy are you? Plan to hand dig or use machines? You could do several things. My dad has successfully chained one to the truck, pulled it over past upright, dug out underneath it on one side, dumped crushed gravel and or concrete, let it back down, pull to the other side and repeat. You could also use a tractor that could lift it out of place, excavate the area and re-do the foundation. If you plan to make it permanent, lay the column down, drill holes and add rebar to them, then upon re-placing it, sink the rebar into a bed of concrete properly prepared.